# How to check Month/day date range

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2008-r2

```
DECLARE @SEASONSTARTDATE date = '1900-03-26'
DECLARE @SEASONENDDATE date = '1900-12-31'
```

With Above data, how do you check if its within the current MONTH and DAY Range.

For example today's date is 2014-04-25 (year is irrelevant), which would mean the above data is valid since its within 3/26 and 12/31.

**EDIT :**

```
declare @SOMEDATA TABLE(
    SEASON_START_DATE datetime,
    SEASON_END_DATE datetime
)

INSERT INTO @SOMEDATA
VALUES ('1900-03-26','1900-12-31')

SELECT * FROM @SOMEDATA
WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()) BETWEEN DATEPART(MONTH,SEASON_START_DATE) AND DATEPART(MONTH,SEASON_END_DATE)
AND DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE()) BETWEEN DATEPART(DAY,SEASON_START_DATE) AND DATEPART(DAY,SEASON_END_DATE)
```

The above should have returned me a result because the current date is in the valid range of  3/26 and 12/31.

The above is not valid because I've broken down the date into month first and compared the months to be in range, and then did the same with day, how can this be done so that it compares just Month and Day with current Month / day to see if the current month/day is within range?

Comment: Define what is a season. Define what you mean by "the above data is valid". I doubt you will get a decent answer if you keep this question in its current state.

Comment: @peter.petrov tried to take a second stab at the question

Comment: I would also give an example of invalid and why it's invalid. I still don't get your question, maybe it's just me...

Comment: @peter.petrov example added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATEPART returns integer.
Use >= and <= instead of BETWEEN.
See if this helps.

Also, seems you have a logical issue there.
For the end date you check only the DAY,
for the start date, you check only the MONTH.

This seems wrong to me.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DT datetime

SET @DT = getdate()
DECLARE @m1 int
SET @m1 = DATEPART(MONTH, SEASON_START_DATE)
DECLARE @m2 int
SET @m2 = DATEPART(MONTH, SEASON_END_DATE)
IF (@m2 < @m1) 
   BEGIN
        SET @m2 = @m2 + 12

        DECLARE @m int
        SET @m = DATEPART(MONTH, @DT)
        IF (@m >= 1 and @m <= @m2) BEGIN SET @m = @m + 12 END
   END


SELECT * FROM @SOMEDATA
WHERE 
@m * 100 + DATEPART(DAY,@dt) >= 
    @m1 * 100 + DATEPART(DAY,SEASON_START_DATE)
AND
@m * 100 + DATEPART(DAY,@dt) <=  
    @m2 * 100 + DATEPART(DAY,SEASON_END_DATE)
```

Comment: The result would remain the same, as I mentioned I've broken the Month and day into seperate conditions , so April = 4 would still be valid for the range of 03 - 12, however the day 25 will not be valid because thats out of range of 26 - 31. The entire month/day comparison has to happen togather - somehow ?!

Comment: Yes, that's the logical issue I mentioned. I showed you how.

Comment: what does the * 100 do, some explanation pls !

Comment: Multiplies the month by 100, so from any date dd/mm you will get one number which looks like this K = mm * 100 + dd. Then you can just compare the respective Ks. This uses the fact that each day (in a month) is either a one digit or two digit number.

Comment: The above does not work if you change the dates to : '1900-03-01' '1900-01-31'....This says from March - Jan the season is valid..

Comment: You should think some more. Your question is not valid.

Comment: Think of it as a Xmas sale season, it starts from Oct and ends in Jan ...so the date would become : 1900-10-01 to 1900-01-31...I've already thought a lot a that's why I posted this since I couldn't figure out the solution!

Comment: OK, then if the month of END_DATE is smaller than the MONTH of the start date, add 12 the month of the end date and then use my algorithm. This will work, man! Think a bit.

Comment: I apologize. Your question is valid and a very good one, you just didn't explain it very well. I still have one bug. Let me fix it.

Comment: OK, check now. This should do it.

Comment: I did one more correction: 'IF (@m >= 1 and @m <= @m2) BEGIN SET @m = @m + 12 END'

Comment: The main idea is that if it's a season say from Oct to Feb, I am first wrapping the months so Feb becomes 12+2 = 14 and Jan becomes 12+1=13. Then I compare using my main logic.

Comment: If you want this to work on the boundary case when start date and end date are in the same month, then you might need some further refinement. But as you define this period as a "season", then I guess you don't have such a scenario i.e. they will always be in different months.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, however I might have a case of Easter season, which will start and end in a week of the same month, I will try to figure it out!

Comment: Actually this might need no tweaking at all. I need to think a bit. Yes, that should be fine as long as the day of the start date is smaller or equal than the day of the end date. If that holds true, you will need no code change at all, I think. Play a bit with it.

Comment: I will try the logic out for all the scenarios and mark this as answered once it satisfies the scenarios, thanks anyways !